# It is possible to resume execution from the point where an exception was raised?

Tags: delphi, exception

There is an example which illustrates my question:

```
procedure Test;
begin
  try
    ShowMessage('1');
    raise EWarning.Create(12345, 'Warning: something is happens!');
    ShowMessage('2');
  except
    on E: EWarning do
      if IWantToContinue(E.ErrorCode) then
        E.SkipThisWarning // shows '1' then '2'
      else
        E.StopExecution;  // shows '1'
  end;
end;

function IWantToContinue(const ErrorCode: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  //...
end;
```

I tried to use something like this:

```
asm
  jmp ExceptAddr
end;
```

but it's wont' work...

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: if your running in IDE then hitting f9 will do the trick i gues

Comment: Don't raise the exception in the first place. Or learn all about Windows SEH and start hacking. The former solution is the tractable one.

Comment: something similar to VB `On Error Resume Next`? (one of main reasons I hate VB is that you don't have normal `try-catch` blocks).

Comment: @kobik: I had the same association (guess we are "[mentally mutilated](http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/e/edsgerdijk201164.html)" :-)). Unfortunately googling for `delphi "On Error Resume Next"` doesn't bring up anything useful.

Comment: @kobik: You're only talking about vb6 and before, right?  `On Error Result Next` was truly monstrous, especially in its handling of errors in subroutines, though `On Error...(do stuff)...Resume` was worse.  On the other hand, vb.net has try-catch blocks which are better than those in C# since they support exception filters.

Comment: @supercat, Indeed. however, I'll always take C# over VB.Net :)

Comment: @kobik: Both languages have annoying limitations.  I mainly use vb.net, but have tried to learn C# well enough to understand it.  If C# would add exception filters, the ability to implement interfaces with protected methods, allow the direct writing of Finalize methods (deprecate the silly "destructor" wrappers), add some better event handling, and allow a choice between early field initialization, late field initialization, constructor-parameter-based field initialization, and const-param pseudo-fields, then I'd likely say it was better than vb.

Answer (score 8):

#### No, it is not possible:

There are two kinds of exceptions: logic exceptions that are raised by the programmer using the `raise` command, and external exceptions that are initiated by the CPU for various conditions: division by zero, stack overflow, access violation. For the first kind, the logic exceptions, there's nothing you can do because they're part of the application "flow". You can't mess with the flow of 3rd party code, you can't even mess with the flow of your own code.

#### External exceptions

Those are normally raised as a consequence of running a single CPU instruction, when that instruction fails. In Delphi those are made available as `EExternal` descendants. The list includes access violations, division by zero, stack overflow, privileged instruction and not-so-many others. Theoretically, for some of those exceptions, the causing condition of the exception could be removed and the single CPU instruction retried, allowing the original code to continue as if no error happened. For example SOME access violations might be "fixed" by actually mapping a page of RAM at the address where the error occurred.

There are provisions in the SEH (Structured Exception Handling) mechanism provided by Windows for dealing with such retry-able errors, and Delphi is using SEH under the hood. Unfortunately Delphi doesn't expose the required elements to make this easily accessible, so using them would be very difficult if not impossible. None the less, for particular types of `EExternal` errors, smart Delphinians might attempt writing custom SEH code and get things working. If that's the case, please ask a new question mentioning the particular type of error you're getting plus the steps you'd like to take to remove the error condition: you'll either get some working code or a customized explanation of why your idea would not work.

#### Logic exceptions initiated through the use of `raise`

Most exceptions fall into this category, because most code will check it's inputs before doing potentially dangerous low level stuff. For example, when trying to access an invalid index in a `TList`, the index would be checked and an invalid index exception raised before attempting to access the requested index. Without the check, accessing the invalid index would either return invalid data or raise an Access Violation. Both of those conditions would be very hard to track errors, so the invalid index exception is a very good thing. For the sake of this question, even if code were allowed to access an invalid index, causing an Access Violation, it would be impossible to "fix" the code and continue, because there's no way to guess what the correct index should be.

In other words, fixing "logic" exceptions doesn't work, shouldn't work, and it's insanely dangerous. If the code that raises the error is yours then you can simply restructure it to NOT raise exceptions for warnings. If that's not your code, then continuing the exception falls into the "insanely dangerous" category (not to mention it's technically not possible). When looking at already written code, ask yourself: would the code behave properly if the `raise Exeption` were replaced with `ShowMessage`? The answer should mostly be `"NO, the code would fail anyway"`. For the very rare, very wrong case of 3rd party code that raises an exception for no good reason, you may ask for specific help on patching the code at run-time to NEVER raise the exception.

Here's what could be in some 3rd party code:

```
function ThirdPartyCode(A, B: Integer): Integer;
begin
  if B = 0 then raise Exception.Create('Division by zero is not possible, you called ThirdPartyCode with B=0!');
  Result := A div B;
end;
```

It should be obvious that continuing that code after the exception is not going to allow stuff to "self heal".

Third party code might also look like this:

```
procedure DoSomeStuff;
begin
  if SomeCondition then
    begin
      // do useful stuff
    end
  else
    raise Exception.Create('Ooops.');
end;
```

Where would that code "continue"? Quite obviously not the `"do usefull stuff"` part, unless the code is specifically designed that way.

Those were, of course, simple examples only scratching the surface. From a technical perspective, "continuing" after an exception as you're suggesting is a lot more difficult then jumping to the address of the error. Method calls use stack space to set up local variables. That space was released in the process of "rolling back" after the error, on the way to your exception handler. `finally` blocks were executed, possibly de-allocating resources where needed. Jumping back to the originating address would be very wrong, because the calling code no longer has what it expects on stack, it's local variables are no longer what they're ment to be.

#### If it's your code that's raising the exception

Your code can *easily* be fixed. Use something like this:

```
procedure Warning(const ErrorText:string);
begin
  if not UserWantsToContinue(ErrorText) then
    raise Exception.Create(ErrorText);
end;

// in your raising code, replace:
raise Exception.Create('Some Text');

// with:
Warning('Some Text');
```

Comment: As I wrote in my previous comments to Ulrich Gerhardt - I can't restructure my code in other way. If its technically not possible to "rolling back" (because stack is released after exception throwing), so there is an answer for my question (see the top): "not, it is not possible".

Comment: I edited the answer to incorporate the blunt answer you apparently expect. My intention was to give you not only the plain fact but explain why that's not going to work and why that's dangerous. You can't mess with the flow of code, and "resuming at the next line" does precisely that, messes with the flow. Again, that's beside the fact that technically the stack is unrolled to reach your exception handler. I'm ignoring that aspect in my explanation because it could be considered an implementation detail: if continuing after an exception would make some sense, an alternative implementation...

Comment: ... of the exception mechanism could be devised where the stack would not actually unroll, allowing the application to "continue". But that's not the case, because exceptions are supposed to stop the execution of current code because continuing is impossible or meaningless.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I know that it can be dangerous, but using exceptions as something that must stop the flow it's just a kind of using them. In most of situations you will do so. But sometimes in rare situations which are affected by many factors you will need something like what I asked. Not because it's not impossible to make it in different way (and maybe more safety). Exception is just a technique which allows you to manage your code.

Comment: So if Delphi could have `unraise` then this code is not meaningless: `try if b = 0 then raise EWarning.Create($DB0, 'division by zero'); c := a / b; except on E: EWarning do if E.ErrorCode = $DB0 then begin b := 1; unraise; end; end;`

Comment: I incorporated a bit of information on the SEH continuation mechanism and what are the candidates for that (even if it's not directly accessible from Delphi). Please re-read my answer, or at least the first half of it.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK no. You have to restructure your code to something like

```
procedure Test;
begin
  ShowMessage('1');
  try
    raise EWarning.Create(12345, 'Warning: something is happens!');
  except
    on E: EWarning do
      if IWantToContinue(E.ErrorCode) then
        // shows '1' then '2'
      else
        raise; // shows '1'
  end;
  ShowMessage('2');
end;
```

Comment: ...which is somewhat braindead. You could easily just ask the question without raising an exception then.

Comment: @Uwe: I guess that depends on how the real code looks like and if the exception originates from third-party code.

Comment: That is not what I want, because instead of `ShowMessage('1'), raise and ShowMessage('2')` will be a function, which can't be changed in a future. I will can only let it to continue its execution (handling `EWarning` and switching a flag as I showed above) or stop it.

Comment: @Victor: Can you add a parameter to this function which specifies whether to throw or not?

Comment: No, because there will be deep stack of calls inside this function with many another functions and much more... All that code will be not know anything about 'exception-throwing-or-not-flag'. I really need something like jumping to code beyond exception throwing (ShowMessage('2') in my case), because there are many others things which prevents me from restructuring the code. Only "jumping back" is acceptable. But thanks for answering anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, it is possible using an SEH `__try/__except` block whose `__except` expression evaluates to `EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION`.

In Delphi, it is not possible to use SEH directly, AFAIK.

Comment: SEH is surely accessible from Delphi. Delphi exception handling is implemented on top of SEH.

Comment: Delphi's exception model is implemened on top of SEH, yes.  But that does not mean that user-written Delphi code can actually write SEH handlers directly.  Delphi exception handlers do not allow users to make use of `GetExceptionCode()`, `GetExceptionInformation()`, or `EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION`.

Comment: And it's not possible to issue some SEH instructions to supersede the Delphi native exception handling?

Comment: Not in native Delphi code, no.  You would have to drop down to the assembly level and write your own SEH code by hand.

Comment: +1. Is this EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION specific to Microsoft's SEH implementation? I'm trying this with the Linux g++ compiler and can't get it to compile.

Comment: AFAIK, SEH is Windows-specific, Linux does not have SEH.  Remember that language-based exception handling (`try/catch` in C++, `try/except` in Delphi) is different than SEH-based exception handling (`__try/__except` or `__try/__catch` in C++, depending on compiler). Language-based exception handling may be based on top of SEH (Embarcadero's implementation is, at least on Windows), but is not a requirement.  For instance, gcc does not support SEH at all, even on Windows (see http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/WindowsGCCImprovements).

Comment: As I can understand right, Delphi does not supports this type of exceptions' handling because it's must be implemented at the compiler  level? Or I can use some assembly language's magic to do this trick? (I mean `asm-end` block in Delphi code)

Comment: You would have to write your own assembly code to create a custom SEH exception handler, yes.  The technical details of how SEH works are on MSDN.

Comment: Could you give me direct link to it please? And how about throwing exceptions of that type in my code manually, not only handling them - is it possible?

Comment: See http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0197/exception/exception.aspx, you can use the Win32 API `RaiseException()` function to raise an SEH exception in code.

Answer (score 0):

BASICally, your code wont work because `ExceptAddr` is a **function**, not a **variable**. So, your code snippet changes as follows:

```
{$O-}
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  try
    OutputDebugString('entering');
    raise Exception.Create('Error Message');
    OutputDebugString('leaving');
  except on E: Exception do
    begin
      OutputDebugString(PChar(Format('ExceptAddr = %p', [ExceptAddr])));
      asm
        CALL  ExceptAddr
        JMP   EAX
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: This code works, but crashes with runtime error when closing application ($O- is also doubtful)... Hope there are more ways for making that...

Comment: Er, what about the stack! You can't just jump into the middle of some random function lord knows where.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan that is probably what is causing the runtime error Victor said.

Comment: @EMBarbosa, yes, stack misalignment is present here, causing outerermost caller to fail. I'd like to spend more time in the RTL's guts, but no promises.

Comment: @user539484 You cannot fix this. You can't put the stack back to where it was when the exception was raised. What about all the finally blocks that have already run? How are you going to undo those. This is just a misthink.

Answer (score 0):

..you could nest multiple try-except and determine if continue inside each exception:

```
try
  try
    some code
  except
    ret := message('want to continue?');
    if ret <> mrYes then
      exit;
  end;
  some other code to perform when no exception or user choose to continue
except
  etc..
end;
```

Comment: You can read my other comments to see why this solution is not acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

This is the example I used.
The following procedure will download files from several URLs (already in dataset form).
The problem is that http often has problems, so a retry mechanism is needed to try to download again. In this example I will try for 3 times, and each time I give 5 seconds sleep. After retry 3 times than will Break;

CDS is TClientDataset
Memo is TMemo
mnuDownload is a TButton or menu

```
uses IDHTTP;

procedure TForm1.mnuDownloadClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  S: String;
  HTTP: TIdHTTP;
  Stream: TMemoryStream;
  iRetry: Integer;

  function DoLoad_HttpXml: Boolean;
  begin
    try
      Result := True;
      HTTP.Get(CDS.FieldByName('url').AsString, Stream);
      Stream.SaveToFile(DataMod.XmlTarget +'\'+ S + IntToStr(CDS.RecNo)+ '.xml');
    except
      on E: Exception do begin
        inc(iRetry);
        Sleep(5000);
        Result := False;
        Memo.Lines.Add('File Number: '+IntToStr(CDS.RecNo)+' will Retry in 5 secs ( Attempt : '+IntToStr(iRetry)+' of 3 )');
      end;
    end;
  end;

begin
  mnuDownload.Enabled := False;
  HTTP := nil;
  Stream := nil;
  iRetry := 0;
  S := FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-', Now);

  Memo.Clear;
  CDS.First;
  HTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  HTTP.HandleRedirects := True;
  Stream := TMemoryStream.Create();

  while not CDS.Eof do begin
    Application.ProcessMessages;
    if iRetry = 3 then Break;
    if DoLoad_HttpXml then begin
      CDS.Edit;
      CDS.FieldByName('status').Value := True;
      CDS.Post;
      CDS.Next;
    end;
  end;

  if Assigned(HTTP) then FreeAndNil(HTTP);
  if Assigned(Stream) then FreeAndNil(Stream);
  mnuDownload.Enabled := True;
  CDS.First;
end;
```

Comment: That is no answer to the actual question.